# Make cmake's find_package(Boost ...) find headers inside conda environment

Tags: boost, cmake, anaconda

I'm trying to build a project on Linux via CMake that depends on Boost. The project's CMakeLists.txt contains the following line:

```
find_package(Boost 1.46 REQUIRED COMPONENTS system thread filesystem)
```

For reproducibility reasons I have installed the required Boost headers via `conda install libboost` so that they are located under 
`~/anaconda3/envs/.../include/boost` instead of `/usr/local/include`. Not when I run `cmake`, I receive an error along the lines of:

```
CMake Warning at /usr/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:761 (message):
  Imported targets not available for Boost version
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:865 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1470 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
  cmake/Dependencies.cmake:5 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:43 (include)
```

What can I do to make CMake find my Boost headers?

Comment: "I receive an error along the lines of" - What you show is a **warning**, not an *error*. The warning by itself doesn't prevent things to work. However, it looks strange that CMake doesn't detect version of the Boost (more popular version of the message is `Imported targets not available for Boost version 106300`). You may also pass additional option `-DBoost_DEBUG=ON` to CMake to get more information about the process to find the Boost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To give CMake a hint, where Boost is installed on your system, you have to set the `BOOST_ROOT` variable accordingly. In your example, this seems to be

```
BOOST_ROOT=~/anaconda3/envs/.../
```

Note that you have to specify the parent directory of the `lib` and `include` folders. The file tree should look like the following:

```
BOOST_ROOT/
|-- include/
|   |-- boost/
|   |   |-- *.hpp
|   |   `-- ...
|   `-- ...
`-- lib/
    |-- libboost_*.so
    `-- ...
```

---

Another note: You are writing about headers only, but keep in mind that those three components you want to use are [*not* header-only](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#header-only-libraries), but are actual libraries that your program has to be linked against.

Comment: You're right, conda actually only installs the header, but this is still useful advice since setting `*_ROOT` also helped me with another library located elsewhere.

Answer (score 4):

This works for me:

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=$CONDA_PREFIX
```

This works because CMake has a well defined search order that it follows when looking for library packages. CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH tells CMake to search in a user specified directory. $CONDA_PREFIX is an environment variable set by Anaconda when you activate your environment. These two tools were designed to work together in this way.